# Make div elements display side by side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draggable

I have two problems in my design.

1. `div` elements beyond parent element's width get wrapped to the next line. (I want them to be in one straight line)
   I tried display inline, block, inline-block, no luck
2. I cant get the divs outside the content div to be hidden. I've already put overflow: hidden, but still something's wrong.

The main issue is, I need the total width of the thumbholder(#thumb_hs) to set the limits for draggable. So when I drag, it drags only till the first line divs.

Edit: The first problem is solved. Thanks to David Thomas.
The other issue was solved by making changes in the javascript parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enforce no wrapping, you can use `white-space: nowrap;` on the parent element, though this requires that `display` on the children is set to either `inline` or `inline-block` (using [`float` will cause the elements to wrap](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Rt46X/3/)):

```
#container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* other stuff */
}

.contained {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Rt46X/1/).

Adding `overflow-x: scroll;` to the `#container` element allows you to, obviously, scroll to the other elements (if you'd like graceful degradation): [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Rt46X/2/).

Comment: Thanks. The first issue is solved. However I'm finding it hard to hide the overflow. Tried the `position:relative;` as mentioned in the other answer but the div somehow shifts.

Comment: Use [`overflow: hidden;`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Rt46X/5/) (or [`overflow-x: hidden`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Rt46X/4/)). Seems to work for me in the demos.

Comment: I've already used `overflow:hidden` on `#thumb_h`, n tried it on `#content` too. But still, don't know why its not working.